# lambda code for latest added object in S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to code lambda function to retrieve the latest added object in and s3 bucket or a folder.

I saw this code online but to me it doesn't make sense, plus it specifies the date manually which is not the aim. The aim is just get the last object added and then I can give it a command to delete, show size or whatever.

```
var S3Latest = require('s3-latest');
var configuration = {
  bucket: 'bucketName',
  before: new Date("Mon, 02 Dec 2013 00:00:00 GMT")
};
```

Comment: S3 has no concept of querying it for "the latest" (most recently added/changed) object... unless your Lambda function is responding to an S3 event notification, which you will want to mention, if that is what this code is for.

Comment: where is your question? what do you want to achieve? just use the module you mentioned in your lambda and care for something wo triggers this function (maybe an event on the s3-Bucket???)